# Rename [certificatestore] → [certificate-store]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would like to propose renaming [certificatestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificatestore) → [certificate-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate-store).

> A location on a computer used to store certificates, often in categories based on usage.

This location is typically referred to as a Certificate Store, two separate words. This can be seen in [Microsoft's official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores).